# Why is all my data defaulting to NULL, while using Knex.js/Objection? I'm not passing useNullAsDefault at all

Tags: javascript, sql, knex.js, objection.js

I'm not passing `useNullAsDefault`, and I've even tried using `useNullAsDefault: false`.

```
const knex = Knex({
    client: 'pg',
    connection: 'postgres://postgres:@localhost:5432/db_development',
});
```

Comment: What are the real values that your table DB has as default?

Comment: There are no default values in the table, is that why they default to null?
Doesn't that make useNullAsDefault useless if it occurs anyway?

Comment: Looks like this `useNullAsDefault` affects only inserts

Comment: My inserts already default to Null I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useNullAsDefault` affects only the case where you are inserting multiple rows in one insert and some of the rows are missing some keys.

You need to setup your schema with default values to prevent NULLs being inserted as default values. You don't have to add that configuration parameter... it is provided just to maintain backwards compatibility for old projects which has been created many years ago.